# uploadify - button fails if not visible in overflow div

Tags: jquery, uploadify

have found that if my uploadify buttons are in a div with vertical scroll
and are not visible (they are further down) then uploadify doesnt work
anyone else come across this?
am i doing something wrong?
thanks MG

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#file_upload_1").uploadify({
        height        : 30,
        swf           : 'uploadify3/uploadify.swf',
        uploader      : 'uploadify3/upload.asp',
        width         : 120
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; overflow:hidden">
    <div style="height:500px; width:200px; overflow-y:scroll">
        <div style="width:200px; height:1000px;"></div>
        <div><input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload_1" /></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if you make it hidden how do you plan to fire the upload action then?

Comment: They are visible but not in the first place he ment. You have to scoll down to see them. Which actually means nothing because they are there on load and everything should work. So my question is: does it work inside a normal non-scrollable div for you? Or didn't you try that?